# Python - How do I notify that a thread has finished to another class?

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk

I'm using a thread to do timed counting (and refreshing stuff in a PyGTK window). It's inside a loop that can vary its range. At the end of each iteration the counter increases and data is printed.  What I want to do is to receive a bang and its data in another class at the end of each tick.

Probably the solution is related to sockets but so far I'm trying to avoid this, so what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is something like this applicable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676485/are-there-any-build-in-cross-thread-events-in-python

Answer (score 5):

The most common solution to pass objects between threads is to use the [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) module:

```
import threading
import Queue
import time

def Worker(queue, n):
    for i in range(n):
        time.sleep(i / 10.0)
        queue.put([i] * i)

q = Queue.Queue()
thread = threading.Thread(target=Worker, args=(q, 10))
thread.start()

results = 10
while results > 0:
    print q.get()
    results -= 1
```

For a better answer, you need to post more specifics.